# Why isn´t angular syncing my var bound with ngModel?

Tags: angular, ngmodel

Good morning,
I started developing with Angular a few weeks ago. Currently I´m running in a problem using ngModel.

**Component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { EventEmitter } from 'protractor';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-toggle-search',
  templateUrl: './toggle-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./toggle-search.component.css']
})
export class ToggleSearchComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private element: ElementRef) { }

  searchTerm = "";

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  toggleUserSubmittedSearchEvent() {
    this.element.nativeElement
      .dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('userSubmittedSearch', {
        detail: this.searchTerm,
        bubbles: true
      }));
  }

  showSearchBar(){
    let searchbar = document.getElementById('searchBar');
    let size = window.innerWidth; 

    searchbar.style.display = "inline-block";
    searchbar.style.width = (size < 600 ? 150 : size/4).toString() + "px"; 
  }

  hideSearchBar(){
    document.getElementById('searchBar').style.display = "none";
  }

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form 
        class="search" 
        (submit)="this.toggleUserSubmittedSearchEvent()" 
        onsubmit="return false"
        (mouseover)="this.showSearchBar()"
        (mouseout)="this.hideSearchBar()"
    >        
        <input [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" type="text" id="searchBar" placeholder="search"/>
        <p>⚲</p>
</form>
```

The function `toggleUserSubmittedSearchEvent()` should dispatch an event containing the `searchterm` entered by the user. The var `searchTerm` should contain the entered string from the input tag. My Problem is that Angular doesn't sync `searchTerm` with the input Tag. What am I missing?

Comment: Try to declare the variables explicitly as 'public'. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but that hasn´t solved the problem.

Comment: Try adding a name attribute to your input : `<input [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" name="seach" `. If that does not work, create a reproducible example on stackblitz

Comment: That worked out well. I will accept this as answer if you copy it from the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do is to add a `name` attribute to your `input` field

```
<input [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" name="search"
```

or add this attribute `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}`

Otherwise, you should get the following error message in the browser's console

```
Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

Example 1: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first">
Example 2: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

More info [here](https://angular.io/guide/forms):

> Defining a name attribute is a requirement when using [(ngModel)] in combination with a form.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using ngModel like that you need to add a name to your input and you need to use interpolation to display the data.

```
    <input [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" type="text" id="searchBar" placeholder="search" name="input"/>
    <p>⚲{{ searchTerm }}</p>
```

You have other issues in your code, but those are not affecting that part.
However, keep in mind that `EventEmitter` must be imported from `@angular/core` and not from `protractor` which is a testing library.

In Angular is a bad practice to access the DOM directly like you are doing it. Use `ViewChild` decorator and Renderer2 service.

**Update**

Using Renderer2 you can manipulate elements without touching the DOM directly.

For a better understanding of this service check the below links:

- [official docs](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2)
- [great explanation of the Renderer2 service](https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/)

Comment: I´m using the viewchild decorator now. But what do you mean in the rendere2 path of your comment? Could you provide any links to understand the whole way of doing it correct?